# Validation of text boxes rendered within a List box

Tags: java, listbox, zk

`

```
   <listitem self="@{each='idSequence'}" value="@{idSequence}">
        <listcell>
            <intbox value="@{idSequence.currentIndex,save-when='Save.onClick'}" constraint="no empty" />
        </listcell>
        <listcell>
            <intbox value="@{idSequence.startIndex}" onBlur="validateStartIndex(self)" constraint="no empty" />
        </listcell>
```

On click of the save button i need to check that the currentIndex is always greater than the startIndex ....

The way i do it currently is to use getSelectedItems and iterate over it to do the validation.

Is there a alternate or better way of doing the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *onBindingSave* event to do so, please take a look at [the document of Databinding Validation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Data_Binding/Validation).

Comment: on the onBindingSave event for say "currentIndex" textbox ,how can i get hold of the value for textbox "startIndex" ? Part of the problem is that the textboxes cannot be given unique id's as they are rendered as part of a listbox

Comment: You can navigate the component tree, like textbox.getParent().getNextSibling().getFirstChild() to get the startIndex value.

Comment: yaa ... that is what i do at present :) .... was wondering if there will be some alternate idiom

Comment: You can use an alternative the ZK 6 Selector to find the component. Please refer to this document - http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/January/Envisage_ZK_6:_An_Annotation_Based_Composer_For_MVC#More_about_Selector